# SQL default NOW() in UTC

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two quick syntax questions that google is not answering for me.

1. How can you create a table in MySQL with a timestamp column and give it a default of the current UTC timestamp?
2. How can you alter a table in MySQL and change the default data type of a timestamp column to provide the current utc timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Times are stored in TIMESTAMP fields as UTC.

To pull a datetime field out of MySQL in UTC, set the timezone on connection:

`SET time_zone = timezone;`

So, you can use that to get the stamp out in UTC format.

As the [MySQL manual states in the time zone section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html):

> Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone
>   to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for
>   retrieval.

To answer your first question, set the field default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.